# Show untracked files in JetBrains intellij for git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using JetBrains IntelliJ.
Is there any possibility to show untracked files in the summary of git before commiting (VCS -> Git -> Commit File...).

In my current configuration the untracked files are always left out. 
So i have to do a 'git status' on the Command line (or look in the file tree for green file entries) to find out about new/untracked files.

I appreciate every Tip.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone viewing this question PLEASE vote on the issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73077 - this issue asks JetBrains to provide a better workflow than we have currently. Thanks :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `Version Control` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>) tool window; then go to `Local Changes` tab and expand `Unversioned Files` group to find all untracked files.

Comment: Ok that makes finding easy without leaving the IDE.
But I hoped for a solution which reminds me if I had forgotten to add untracked files (i have countless commits which starts with 'added missed untracked files' ;-) ).

Comment: There is a feature request for what you want: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73077.

Comment: In the Version Control -> Local Changes view, I had to explicitly refresh first for it to show my unversioned files, even though the Project view already showed them. (Using IDEA 15.0.3).