# Adding new files to git via IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

New file has been created inside scripts directory

[image]

Meanwhile IDEA says that no changes were detected (which is true, no changes to committed files took place, yet new file was added)

[image]

Once file is added manually

[image]

IDEA now allows it to be committed

[image]

How can i configure IDEA to detect new files and allow them to be added (if added from outside of IDEA)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show untracked files in JetBrains intellij for git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746106/show-untracked-files-in-jetbrains-intellij-for-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDEA doesn't show new files in the `Commit Project` dialog, vote for:

- [IDEA-73077](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73077) Commit Changes: add option to show unversioned files there

Your question is also a duplicate of

- [Show untracked files in JetBrains intellij for git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746106/show-untracked-files-in-jetbrains-intellij-for-git).

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out how to add multiple files to git versioning easily:

1. Open 'Changes' window
2. If you have unversioned files, there will be a "Unversioned Files" category in the tree view.
3. If you want to add all of those files at once, right click "Unversioned Files" and choose "Add to VCS"
4. If there are alot of files to add, it will show something like "View all unversioned files". Select the files you want and click the "+" sign on the left to add the files

There may be more cases I could've covered, but the above should be enough for you to figure out the rest :P

Note: this means that the workflow above would work not only for Git, but with other VCS.

Comment: How do you get to the changes window?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that IntelliJ has Git configured to point into the same directory.  Then, hit the Synchronize button (the blue "refresh" button) so that IntelliJ can pick up the changes made to the file system.  It typically does this on its own and is fairly automatic, but sometimes it may not synchronize for a while.

Comment: Tried this without effect. Added new file, synchronized - IDEA did not know anything new was added to project.